# \boldsymbol and \it not work

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, cjk, math-fonts

Our project formula uses \it and \boldsymbol, but it doesn't work since we upgrade texlive from 2016 to 2022. I doubt it might be the problem of font?

The formula:

- ${\it v} _x＝{\it v} _0$，$x＝{\it v} _0t$
- $\overrightarrow {AB}=\boldsymbol {a}+5\boldsymbol {b}$

The doubtful error message:

- Font "Source Han Serif CN" does not contain(fontspec) requested Script "CJK".
- Font "Times New Roman" does not contain requested(fontspec) Script "Math".
- OpenType feature 'Style=MathScript' (ssty) not(fontspec) available for font 'Times New Roman' with script(fontspec) 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.
- OpenType feature 'Style=MathScriptScript' (ssty) not(fontspec) available for font 'Times New Roman' with script(fontspec) 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.
- Font "BabelStone Han" does not contain requested(fontspec) Script "CJK".
- Font "XITS" does not contain requested Script "CJK".
- Font "Symbola" does not contain requested Script(fontspec) "CJK".
- Font shape `TU/TeXGyreTermesMath(1)/b/n' undefined(Font) using` TU/TeXGyreTermesMath(1)/m/n' instead
- pubRuby.sty: Package `CJK' can not be loaded with` xeCJK'.
- pubRuby.sty: You have requested, on input line 31, version `1996/11/20' of package CJK, but only version` \ver@CJK.sty ' is available.
  The latex and packages version:
- pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022)
- unicode-math: 2020/01/31 0.8q
- amsmath: 2022/04/08 v2.17n

The key source code:

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSa}{U}{msa}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{AMSb}
\let\Bbb=\mathbb

\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpropto} {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"5F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\thicksim}  {\mathrel}{AMSb}{"73}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\thickapprox}    {\mathrel}{AMSb}{"74}

\DeclareSymbolFont{rmlargesymbols}{U}{euex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rmintop}{\mathop}{rmlargesymbols}{82}

\RequirePackage[bold-style=ISO, mathbf=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular}
[
    Extension = .otf,
    BoldFont = XITSMath-Bold,
    range={"1D70B, "2605, "2ACB, "2AFD, "23DC}
]
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular}
[
    Extension = .otf,
    BoldFont = XITSMath-Bold,
    range={"2A00-"2AFF}
]
```

```
\RequirePackage[CJKmath=true, CheckSingle=true, AutoFallBack]{xeCJK}
\RequirePackage{xeCJKfntef}
\xeCJKsetup{CJKspace=true, underline/skip=false}

\setCJKmainfont[AutoFakeBold,
               AutoFakeSlant,
               BoldFont=Source~Han~Serif~CN~Bold,
               ItalicFont=Source-Sa3mSerifCN-Regular,
               GeneralPunctuation=BabelStone~Han,
               Arrows=XITS,
               MathematicalOperators=XITS,
               SimLikeMathematicalOperators=Tutor~Pub~Custom,
               BoxDrawing=BabelStone~Han,
               GeometricShapes=XITS,
               Symbols=Symbola]{Source~Han~Serif~CN}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont=TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT]{TeXGyreTermes-Regular}
\newfontfamily{\enitshape}{TeXGyreTermes-Italic}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largeSymbolsExt}{OMX}{yhex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\wideparen}{\mathord}{largeSymbolsExt}{"F3}

\xeCJKsetcharclass{"20000}{"30000}{1}
\setCJKfallbackfamilyfont
    {\CJKrmdefault}
    [AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant,CircledNumbers=STSong]
    {STSongti-SC-Regular,TH-Sung-TP2}

\usepackage[CJK]{pubRuby}
```

Comment: You should provide the complete code such that the error message can be reproduced.

Comment: @Stephen our project is so large and contains other useless defined commands, this is the key source code.

Comment: Even if this is the key source code, you can simply add the documentclass and `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and a small sample, so that it becomes complete. That way you will motivate people to help you.

Comment: Remove these "useless defined commands" and the document source which doesn't include the problem. Then you get full document which you can test if it still demonstrates the problem. If it is true then put such minimal but full document here, because people here cannot start to solve the problem without such testing document.

Comment: I can't check it, for lack of complete source code, but.... `\it` has been deprecated since... 1992? Could be not related, but you're supposed to use `\mathit{v}` or `\textit{v}`. (Probably not related, but well).

Comment: None of the warnings or error messages you show is in any way related to `\it` or `\boldsymbol`. By the way, `\it` has been deprecated for about 30 years; a math mode “v” is simply input as `v`: why complicating things?

Answer (score 3):

With TexLive 2022 on Windows, running this code in xelatex:

MWE

`\it` is not needed and `\boldsymbol{}` replaced by `\symbf{}`.

(I don't have all the CJK fonts, and `pubRuby` package commented out because not found (1996 is very old).)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSa}{U}{msa}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{AMSb}
\let\Bbb=\mathbb

\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpropto} {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"5F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\thicksim}  {\mathrel}{AMSb}{"73}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\thickapprox}    {\mathrel}{AMSb}{"74}

\DeclareSymbolFont{rmlargesymbols}{U}{euex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rmintop}{\mathop}{rmlargesymbols}{82}

\usepackage[bold-style=ISO, mathbf=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular}
[
    Extension = .otf,
    BoldFont = XITSMath-Bold,
    range={"1D70B, "2605, "2ACB, "2AFD, "23DC}
]
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular}
[
    Extension = .otf,
    BoldFont = XITSMath-Bold,
    range={"2A00-"2AFF}
]

\usepackage[CJKmath=true, CheckSingle=true, AutoFallBack]{xeCJK}
\usepackage{xeCJKfntef}
\xeCJKsetup{CJKspace=true, underline/skip=false}
%
%\setCJKmainfont[AutoFakeBold,
%               AutoFakeSlant,
%               BoldFont=Source Han Serif CN Bold,
%               ItalicFont=Source-Sa3mSerifCN-Regular,
%               GeneralPunctuation=BabelStone Han,
%               Arrows=XITS,
%               MathematicalOperators=XITS,
%               SimLikeMathematicalOperators=Tutor Pub Custom,
%               BoxDrawing=BabelStone Han,
%               GeometricShapes=XITS,
%               Symbols=Symbola]{Source Han Serif CN}
               
\setmainfont[ItalicFont=TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT]{TeXGyreTermes-Regular}
\newfontfamily{\enitshape}{TeXGyreTermes-Italic}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largeSymbolsExt}{OMX}{yhex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\wideparen}{\mathord}{largeSymbolsExt}{"F3}

\xeCJKsetcharclass{"20000}{"30000}{1}
%\setCJKfallbackfamilyfont
%    {\CJKrmdefault}
%    [AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant,CircledNumbers=STSong]
%    {STSongti-SC-Regular,TH-Sung-TP2}

%\usepackage[CJK]{pubRuby}


\begin{document}
text

    $v_x＝v_0$，$x＝v_0t$

text
    
    \bigskip
    $\overrightarrow {AB}=\symbf {a}+5\symbf {b}$

text

text mode:

Aa                       

math mode:

$Aa                       $

\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image: math]

Math looks OK, including ISO bold.

Note:
TexGyreTermes Math already has the Unicode block for Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols (including the bold math alphabets), so does not need a bold text font.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much!